# isscalar function for user defined classes

Tags: class, octave

I have a class that stores a matrix among other properties.
In the class I overload the size function to return the size of the matrix and that works fine.
The problem is when I use isscalar(a) with a being an instance of the class. This function returns 1 when I was expecting 0.

According to the documentation:
isscalar (x)

```
Return true if x is a scalar.

A scalar is an object with two dimensions for which size (x) returns [1, 1]
```

The code works as expected in matlab.
What is going on here?

Comment: since MATLAB compatibility is generally considered a necessary feature of octave code handling, this may warrant a bug report over at bugs.octave.org. can you provide a trivial class example along with the matlab and octave behavior to create a report sufficient for them to act on? also, is this a classdef class or a 'traditional' @folder class?

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a scalar: there is a single object. `builtin('size', obj)` would return `[1,1]`. (Note that you can create arrays of objects!) The function `isscalar` doesn't actually call `size`, it is a builtin function that has direct access to the size property of the array, no M-file code execution is involved. The same is true for functions such as `length` (which returns `max(size())`) and `numel` (which returns `prod(size())`).

But you can overload `isscalar` just like you overloaded `size` to work on the matrix inside your object instead:

```
function res = isscalar(obj)
   res = isscalar(obj.matrix);
end
```

If you want to overload the `size` function, you need to overload a bunch of other functions too, in order for things to remain consistent.